# Is there a way to have parallel for-each loops?

Tags: python, foreach, iteration, parallel-processing

Let's say I have 2 lists in Python and I want to loop through each one in parallel - e.g. do something with element 1 for both lists, do something with element 2 for both lists... I know that I can do this by using an index:

```
for listIndex in range(len(list1)):
   doSomething(list1[listIndex])
   doSomething(list2[listIndex])
```

But is there a way to do this more intuitively, with a foreach loop? Something like `for list1Value in list1, list2Value in list2`...?

I've currently run into this situation in Python, but this is a longstanding question and I'd be interested to know if you can do this in any language. (I just assumed that Python is the most likely to have a method of dealing with this.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for (a,b) in zip(list1, list2):
  doSomething(a)
  doSomething(b)
```

Though if `doSomething()` isn't doing I/O or updating global state, and it just works on one of the elements at a time, the order doesn't matter so you could just use `chain()` (from itertools):

```
for x in chain(list1, list2):
  doSomething(x)
```

Apropos, `from itertools import *` is something I do very often. Consider `izip()` instead of using the `zip()` I gave above. Also look into `izip_longest()`, `izip(count(), lst)`, etc. Welcome to functional programming. :-)

Oh, and zipping also works with more "columns":

```
for idx, a, b, c in izip(count(), A, B, C):
  ...
```

Comment: one example of no globality and no applicability of chain: `for item1, item2 in zip(iter1, iter2): fileobj.write("%s %s\n" % (item1, item2))`

Comment: thanks this is great! just a quick question... does this method require the lists to be of the same length? what happens if they're not?

Comment: It stops as soon as the shorter list is exhausted.

Comment: @froadie, you can use izip_longest() to make it 'pad' the shortest lists with fill values (defaults to None).

Also, updated answer somewhat.

Comment: Second example, shouldn't it be `doSomething(x)`?

Answer (score 4):

That will depend on the language. Python actually has a rather simple method for that:

```
a = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
b = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
for pair in zip(a,b):
  print("%d => %s" % pair)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` or `itertools.izip` for this:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(iterable1, iterable2):
    # process the items in parallel
```

`itertools.izip` in Python < 3 and `zip` in Python ≥ 3 return iterators; i.e. they provide tuples of pairs (or triplets, quartets etc) on request. Python < 3 `zip` creates a list of tuples, so the memory requirements could be large if the smallest of the sequences is quite long.