# accessing two or more list in a single for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

provided that I have two lists in same length, list_a, list_b.

I can print they items in a single for loop as follows:

```
for i in range(0, len(list_a)):
    print "%s %s" % (list_a[i], list_b[i])
```

is there any alternative and elegant way to do above mentioned task ?

I have tried

```
for a, b in list_a, list_b:
    print ""
```

Comment: Search, search, search.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229458/is-there-a-way-to-have-parallel-for-each-loops

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
     # whatever
```

When the lists are long and you are using Python 2.x, you might prefer [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to save some memory.

Answer (score 0):

Or you also able to use the following statement to combine lists:

```
map(lambda x,y,z: (x,y,z), list_a, list_b, list_c)
```

Comment: This can also be done by `map(None, list_a, list_b, list_c)`.  The difference to `zip()` is that the length of the resulting list is equal to the longest sequence.  It's preferable to use `itertools.izip_longest()` though.

Comment: Yes, you are right))) Thank you, will start using this in my code.